# Integration by Symmetry

Tags: integration

> Let $R = \{(x,y): –a \le x \le a, –b \le y 
> \le b\}$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers.
>
> Evaluate the following integral using symmetry arguments:
>   $$
> \iint_R\frac{\sin(x-y)}{x^2+y^2+1}dA
> $$

I'm not sure where to begin on this one. Using a compound angle formula doesn't help and partial fractions can't be used. What do I do?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  These are all separate questions; please post them as such.  Also, for each one, please add some information about what you have tried and where you are getting stuck; people here are generally much more willing to help if you do.

Comment: Try a simpler problem. Try integrating $\sin(x)$ from $-a$ to $a$. After you've done that, think if there's an easier way using a symmetry argument.
Consider using some notation tricks to prove your symmetry argument.

Comment: How both the integral and domain $R$ change under the transformation $(x, y) \mapsto (-x, -y)$?

Answer (score 1):

Can you break up $R$ into pieces that relate to each other in a simple way? The "using symmetry arguments" is a strong clue, and is really the first place to start with this one, before you even think about any fancy integration tricks.